# Linux, Putty, "table" characters

Tags: linux, putty, characters

I used Putty to login into a Linux server.

The "problem" that in MC I see "a with ^", and not "|" in table.

How can I change this in putty to I see the MC as in Norton Commander/DOS.

Comment: In Putty's config window, try to fix the character encoding and font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [choroba](https://superuser.com/users/105002/choroba)'s comment says,

The terminal-emulator and the server must agree about the character set and encoding that is being used.

On Linux you need to check what the environment variable $LANG is set to. There are other environment variable that can influence this but setting $LANG should work. e.g. `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

On Putty you change settings -> Windows -> Translation -> Remote character set. e.g. `UTF8`. You may also need to specify a font that contains the specific characters used by MC.

If MC ignores LANG and uses a specific character set (e.g. CP850 or CP437), you'd have to change Putty settings to match that.